# Somar no SQL base em uma letra

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Boa tarde!

Em uma banco de dados tenho duas tabelas. Uma chamada Contas, onde tem por exemplo uma coluna de contas 1(Ativo), 1111(Caixa), 1112(Bancos), 1113(Recebimentos).

Outra tabela chamada Valores onde tem o valor das contas, porém esta tabela possui somente valores das contas com 4 dígitos. Ex: 1111(Caixa).

Preciso realizar a soma de todas as contas que o primeiro carácter seja "1", assim obtendo o valor da conta 1(Ativo).

Muito obrigado desde já.

Comment: O que você tentou?

Comment: Na tabela de contas não tem um campo que indique a natureza da conta ( ativo , passivo ou resultado)  ? Seria mais "limpo" um join e tratar este campo .

Comment: Boa tarde! Consegui resolver, criei relacionamentos entre as tabelas e os valores se ajustaram automaticamente. Muito obrigado